# qty_ordered on product grid magento 1.9.2

Tags: zend-framework2, left-join, magento-1.9

I create a script to show the qty_ordered from the table sales_flat_order_item.
But now i want only the qty_ordered when the order is on pending, processing.

But i dont know how i can do that.
I search on the internet but no results.

I create a LeftJoin for this.

```
$totalOrderedQuery = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read')
            ->select()
            ->from('sales_flat_order_item', array('product_id', 'qty_ordered' => 'SUM(`qty_ordered`)'))
            ->group('product_id');

        $collection->joinField('qty_ordered', $totalOrderedQuery, 'qty_ordered', 'product_id=entity_id', null, 'left');
```

and i show with

```
        $this->addColumn('qty_ordered',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('test'),
                'width' => '70px',
                'type'  => 'number',
                'index' => "qty_ordered"
            ));
```

its in the GRID.

can somebody pls help me.
thank you.